# What is a reasonable minimum version of libstdc++ to require for C++11 support

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

Apple no longer advances GCC or libstdc++ on their platform, but they do ship clang. By default, when compiling with the Apple provided clang in C++11 mode, the default standard library is still libstdc++, which is too old to function reasonably in C++11 mode.

I'd like to test the __GLIBCXX__ value at configure time and reject attempts to build in C++11 mode against a "too old" libstdc++, like the one that Apple ships. So I'd need to pick a reasonable minimum version.

While GCC does a great job of enumerating language feature support in different releases of the compiler with [this table](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), I can't find an analogous table that shows the library features as supported by each libstdc++ release. This makes it hard to choose a reasonable minimum, especially if my project depends on particular library features when compiled in C++11 mode.

What is the earliest release of libstdc++ that offers some meaningful level of support for C++11 library features? I realize this is a subjective question - I'm looking more for guidance from those who have decided this issue in their own projects. As bounds, libstdc++ 4.2 is obviously "out" and 4.8 is pretty clearly "in". Where would you draw the line if you were deciding this for your project, and why?

Comment: Why not use a `configure` script (or `CmakeLists.txt` file) to check for the features you need?

Comment: Long term (like a few weeks), yes, that is clearly the way to go. Short term, I want to prevent users from setting themselves up for obvious failure with a coarse check for a "reasonably recent" libstdc++. I'd like a big hammer right now, to be replaced later with more refined tools.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you have any reference how to check for C++11 features in a CMakeLists.txt? Sounds useful!

Comment: @TemplateRex Just added a couple of examples [here](http://pileborg.se/2013/06/using-cmake-to-check-for-c11-features/).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Great, that's a neat trick, compiling a few oneliners with the feature that you want to test for. A bit like SFINAE ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with 4.4 or 4.5, they implement C++0x drafts that differ from the final standard in some important ways. 4.6 has pretty good support with all the important parts (move semantics, `<type_traits>`, `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `<thread>`, `<mutex>`, `<tuple>`, unordered containers, `bind`, `function`,  ...)  and 4.7 is probably 90% complete.

You should be able to tell from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++/manual/status.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/libstdc++/manual/status.html but the links are broken for some reason.

The support in 4.7 is currently very close to that in 4.8, shown at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: you have 2 links out of 3 that are dead

Comment: I know, did you read what I said? _"the links are broken for some reason."_  I've [reported it](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2013-06/msg00045.html) so it will be fixed and the links will work.

Answer (score 0):

to be picky gcc is not libstdc++ meaning that one is a compiler and the other one is a standard library, but since they are usually distributed in the same package, you can refer to [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and see what you need and in what version of GCC that given feature is available.

Comment: Except that page only covers language features implemented by G++, which is completely irrelevant if using libstdc++ with clang, not G++